# Grails/Hibernate - query associations

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, executequery

I am struggling with a Grails(Hibernate) query.

I have a table (ExamLog) that tracks each time an exam question is modified in a test bank.

The ExamLog table has the following attributes: logId(PK), exam(FK), question(FK), comments, oldMark, newMark, dateModified.
The Exams table has the following attributes: examId(PK), questionsId(FK), lastUsed, versionCode ...etc,
The Questions table has the following attributes: questionID(PK), description, difficultyLevel, avgPassed, ...etc.

My domains looks like this:

```
  class ExamLog{
       Exams exam;
       Questions question;
       String comments;
       Integer oldMark;
       Integer newMark;
       String dateModified;

       static belongsTo = [exam: Exams, question: Questions]
  }


  class Exams{
       Question questions;
       Integer versionCode;
       Integer lastUsed;
  }


  class Questions{
       String description;
       Integer difficultyLevel;
       Boolean avgPassed;
  }
```

I am trying to get a list of questions for each exam in which avgPassed=false so that I can then count how many questions in the testbank have been failed;

I have looked at examples on StackOverflow but am still having difficulties. This is what I have tried but I am not getting the correct results with either method.
Using sql:

```
  ExamLog.executeQuery("Select exam_log.exam_id, count(avgPassed) from exam_log, question where exam_log.exam_id = question.exam_id group by(exam_log.exam_id");
```

Using Grails Hibernate Criteria:

```
  def outstanding = ExamLog.createCriteria().list{
     projections{
         exams{
             questions{
                 eq("avgPassed",false)
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: you really name your variable like that `avgPassed>70` ?  I'm speechless...

Comment: I don't think he/she does name it that because I don't think that would even compile.